# Heroku "Cannot run more than 1 Free size dynos" but I'm only trying to run one

Tags: java, heroku, jar, scheduler, twitter4j

I am trying to run a command to run a one-off dyno once per hour for my app. All it does is run my code as a jar file and then sleep until the next hour when it runs again.

My current scheduler command to run is

```
heroku run:detached java -jar TwitterAutoBot.jar
```

`TwitterAutoBot.jar` is the jar file that is my code to run. This command that I use for the scheduler works in git bash. The program runs perfectly then stops. But when it attempts the command with the scheduler, it says

> Cannot run more than 1 Free size dynos

Running `heroku ps` shows that there are no active dynos for this app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scheduler [launches a one-off dyno](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler#dyno-hour-costs) when it runs your command. And your command tries to launch another (via `heroku run`). Try this command instead:

```
java -jar TwitterAutoBot.jar
```